# storage lucene index in database using data objects in java

Tags: lucene, match, fuzzy-search

Is this possible? I cannot access the database directly--only through data objects. 
Would I be able to search the index if the items are returned in something like ArrayList?

If this is not possible, is there some way I can use Lucene (or some other tool) to do fuzzy matching against an object using java?

For example, I have a Person object that has a FirstName and LastName. I want to do a fuzzy match on the name. 
So, say I have an array of x amount of Person objects, would there be an efficient way of looping through each Person object and comparing the names?

Answer (score 0):

Take those data objects and build a separate Lucene index over them, storing the fields you need. Using your Person example, every Lucene document would be [Id, FirstName, LastName]. A search on this index would return the Id required to query your database for the complete data object.

The actual indexing is easy, you just need to retrieve a list of data objects, iterate them, generate Lucene documents, and store them using an IndexWriter. You could work against either a filesystem directory for persistent storage, or a in-memory storage.

Answer (score 0):

Those are the possible solutions I came up with--
however, I cannot store my index on FSDirectory (project specs do not allow this) and for RAMDirectory, there are going to be thousands of Person objects we'll need to search through so I don't know if in-memory storage is ideal for this situation.

Is there any other sort of fuzzy match algorithm I can use that will be efficient for large sets of data?

Comment: I believe this is a comment to by answer. A few thousand documents aren't any problems for Lucene, and ten thousand documents of 1 kb each is still only 10 mb of memory. I dont know what fzzu algorithm you're planning to use, but you may want to look into the BKTree structure which can be used with the Levensthein distance to allow fuzzy matches.